# Performance of parameter object vs long parameter list

Tags: java, performance, memory, jvm, stack

I understand the reason for using a parameter object when it comes to handling methods with long parameter lists. But I have a situation where I would like to reduce the memory footprint of my code.

> The question I have is from a performance perspective.  How much
>   benefit would I get by going to a long parameter list?

The use case is that these methods will end up being called thousands of times and every time a call is made, a new parameter object is created. I want to really avoid creating all those parameter objects.

Is there a "I can have my cake and eat it too" solution of encapsulating the parameters and only using stack storage?

Unfortunately there are multiple methods in the call chain needing all those parameters, and I don't mind making this change since these methods are not public. Just wanted to know of a better performing solution.

Making this change will impact a large portion of the code and will take a lot of my time. Just want to check if this is a worthwhile change to make before I take this route.

**Data structure**

The data structure is an object graph. The objects are the business data and the edges connecting them are the calls. These edges are associated with the parameter data. Using parameter objects is beautiful and my code works very well. But I am not satisfied with the performance and want to improve it.

I have profiled my code and these objects are one significant part of the memory overhead. I doubt if they contribute much to the CPU overhead, but am definitely concerned about memory.

> This data structure will be part of a framework that will be used in a
>   highly concurrent environment. So reducing memory footprint is of utmost concern to me.

The parameter object has about 10 fields and some behavior associated with it. I can always encapsulate the behavior alternatively.

Comment: Have you given any thought  to whether a builder pattern might be appropriate based on the things you do later downstream with this parameter list?

Comment: Couldn't you just use a JSON object to store the list of your arguments, why create an object/class?

Comment: Please note, that each call is unique and has different values, so I cannot build an object and share it.

Comment: An alternative to hexafraction's great suggession, you may consider composite pattern.

Comment: Could you please describe how these patterns address the memory issue?

Comment: Calling a method "thousands" of times is not all that much nowadays.  Even if your parameter object were itself 1000 bytes of extra over the individual objects (very unlikely) , that's only a megabyte. Some dog collars have more memory than that.  :-)  Only if you are calling this method millions of times should you be concerned.

Comment: Please note that this needs to work in a highly concurrent environment. Yes, milliions of times is a possibility.

Comment: This is almost certainly pointless. Object creation and management is one of the core tasks the JVM is optimized for, and it's entirely ordinary to generate hundreds of objects for the simplest HTTP call in a Wrb application. Don't worry about it.

Comment: The parametef objects themselves dont eat much memory, its the business data itself, right?  If so, changing to a long parameter list wont help much, as there are still these large business objects.  Are the parameter objects using all the memory not getting garbage collected after use?  That is where I would look.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of techniques.

If you are worried about memory overhead, you can create a fixed pool of parameter objects, and then clear them out when they are released to the pool.  That way you fetch a parameter object from the pool, set the values (which I hope are primitives) and then pass it along.  Once done, you relinquish the parameter object to the pool which then permits it to be reused.

Keep in mind that object creation in Java doesn't have the same performance as object creation in C++ or other languages (where objects are typically very expensive to create).  In some cases, additional objects don't cost much if anything at all, due to JVM optimizations a single object creation often mallocs the memory needed to support half a dozen or more 'new' invocations.

Finally, as to using stack storage, there is support for "stack storage" of objects in Java, but to keep it in line with the language design, it is done at the JVM's bequest and has the same presentation in the code as heap stored objects.  I'm not fully familiar with the techniques one would use to get their objects poised for possible stack storage, but I do know that you couldn't guarantee it.

Comment: "If you are worried about memory overhead, you can create a fixed pool of parameter objects, and then clear them out when they are released to the pool."  In a highly concurrent environment, this solution can be expected to have more liveness and safety concerns.  For many kinds of objects, the JVM's garbage collector will outperform an object pool (as you indicate).

Comment: @scottb For most use cases, I'd agree.  People rarely do enough work to actually prove they beat the garbage collector, and it's not an easy piece of code to beat.  For some rare cases (LMAX) it is a different game.  They use a non-garbage collected circular buffer to great effect, but in doing so, they redefine "grabbing" and "using" objects to not mean the object's lifetime on the heap, but rather it being marked as "before" the writing index or after the "last reader" index (with circular wrapping of the indices.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your situation. The chief issues with object creation (in resource-lacking environments) are memory consumption, and object creation time.

In most cases, object creation time is a snap if you don't have numerous nested objects. For memory cost, count up the number of primitives and multiply them by their respective memory cost, then add eight bytes for the object itself. (And of course do this recursively for any contained objects.)

For the case of Strings, it's roughly (40 + 2*character count) bytes. This is obviously subject to change, but not dramatically. For basic arrays, multiply the primitive cost by the capacity, then add sixteen.

O-notation of creation is basically the O-notation of your constructor. I'm sure there's a little overhead, but it's nothing significant. For a simple parameter object, it's probably inconsequential.

Not to crowd your schedule, but the best possible approach, if efficiency is that important and the answer isn't obvious, is to run benchmarks on both approaches.

As I said, I don't know your exact situation. However, I've solved similar problems in the past with intelligent deviations on the Factory pattern. However, that would require yet another class, and it sounds like that is an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

> The question I have is from a performance perspective. How much
>   benefit would I get by going to a long parameter list?

There are a variety of reasons for avoiding long parameter lists, all of which are expounded in the treatment of the Builder pattern in Effective Java, 2nd Ed.

If your method is part of an internal class that will be used and maintained only by you, then there is probably no harm in going with many parameters.  But there are some facts to keep in mind.  Long parameter lists:

- make your code very much harder to read
- can increase the likelihood of difficult-to-debug errors, esp. if the list contains multiple parameters of the same type that can be inadvertently transposed
- cause your program to be difficult to maintain
- can doom your API if the method is exported to clients who will be unable to use the method without frequent access to documentation

The fact is that the impact of optimizations (such as telescoping parameter lists) is frequently and commonly overstated.  Yes, the JVM will shave some cycles off the execution of a method using the telescoping pattern ... but consider that if that method comprises less than 10% of the total CPU processing of your whole project (common), then the optimization is worthless.

> "First make your program correct, and then ... and only then ... make
>   it fast, but only if profiling indicates that you need to."

In fact, the optimization relative to the many benefits of, say, using a builder pattern on a bundling object for a method that needs lots of parameters can be expected to cause you to lose time and money.

> The use case is that these methods will end up being called thousands
>   of times and every time a call is made, a new parameter object is
>   created. I want to really avoid creating all those parameter objects.

For modern JVMs, the processing time used for creating and garbage collecting short-lived lightweight objects typically outperforms object pooling.

Your concerns are valid, but you really need to perform profiling to see if there is a memory or performance reason to do an optimization.  This is especially true if the cost of the optimization may cost you in other ways down the road (maintainability, readability).

Comment: This sentence from your question gives me pause: "Making this change will impact a large portion of the code and will take a lot of my time. Just want to check if this is a worthwhile change to make before I take this route."  My expectation is that the investment of time to make the optimization plus the decrease in maintainability and readability will not be justified by the memory benefit.

Comment: I am not that concerned about maintenance, since I have built quite a large suite of test cases to catch issues. Will by adding more as necessary. But yes, I need to check the memory benefit with this change and was hoping others have done some similar exercise before.

Comment: What you'll be doing is using a JVM stack frame to contain the parameters you'll be passing instead of allocating them into the heap.  Overall, the net memory improvement will be slight, perhaps as little as one reference pointer.  Your method will need to get its data one way or another, either on the stack or through the heap.  If profiling confirms a concern with available heap memory, then I'd say you have a reason to try this optimization.  Just bear in mind that if your parameters are already reference types then they're in the heap already.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation this is what I found.

Replacing parameter objects with long parameter list is not going to improve performance unless the following is true

> The parameter objects are not held longer than necessary in the memory

What I learnt from this exercise helped shed light on the object lifecycle of the parameter objects

It helped ensure that the parameter objects were indeed short lived and not shared in other parts of the code unnecessarily. I had to do a little bit of refactoring to ensure this and I ended up keeping the parameter objects.